# angular 4 - checkbox '✓' disappears after changing view

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have to make a simple view of the quiz. There is a variable 'question' which has an array of answers - 'trainingAnswers[]'. 
[image: view]

Each answer has a 'select' variable that is assigned to the checkbox. When you select an answer, true or false is assigned to the answer, but after going to the next question and returning to the previous one, the checkbox is unchecked (value is fine, previously checked answer has value 'true' at 'selected', but "✓" sign disappears).

My part of this code:

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of filteredQuestions;">
    <div>Question {{pager.index + 1}} of {{pager.count}}.</div>
     <h2>{{pager.index + 1}}.<span [innerHTML]="question.question"></span></h2>

          <div class="answers" *ngFor="let answer of question.trainingAnswers">
              <label class="" [attr.for]="answer.id">
                  <input id="{{answer.id}}" type="checkbox" name="answer.id" [(ngModel)]="answer.selected" (change)="onSelect(question, answer);" />
                         {{answer.answer}}
              </label>
          </div>
    </div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker/stackblitz?

Comment: and could you provide the onSelect method in your ts file

Comment: @Plog here it i:

 onSelect(question: TrainingQuestion, answer: TrainingAnswer) {
    question.trainingAnswers.forEach((x) => {
      if (x.id !== answer.id) {
        x.selected = false;
      }
    });
  }

Comment: Just an idea but run a debugger to see if onChange is getting called when you change questions